# Accesing the output of grouped data in Pandas DataFrame python

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the pandas DataFrame groupby feature.Below is a sample code

```
df.groupby('type').size()
```

Output :

```
>>> df.groupby('type').size()
type
strongsubj    10
weaksubj       4
dtype: int64
```

Can you please suggest a way so that I can access the value 10 for the keyword "strongsubj".

I am sure there must some easiest way, but I am struggling hard for the same. Any leads would be appreciable.

Thanks,
Brajen

Comment: `df1 =df.groupby('type')` ??

Comment: Thats the code I was using

Comment: Nope, its not working. can you please check the output section where i have mentioned df and its output  and then answer the question.

Comment: Ah! tried `df.groupby('type').size()['strongsubj']` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below-

```
df.groupby('type').size()['strongsubj']
```